# Horizontal Scroll Bar appearing on Page Tab

Tags: facebook, iframe, scrollbar

how can I remove horizontal scroll bar appearing on page tab.  I had a designer create the reveal page and am uncertain what to change to the html file to make the scroll disappear.  It is the welcome page on this fanpage http://www.facebook.com/pages/MaidPro-of-Northern-Cincinnati/154767811271566?sk=app_214902645232913

This is the current code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="SiteGrinder 2  http://www.medialab.com/sitegrinder" />
<title>maid_pro</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection"  href="maidpro.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="maidpro">
<div id="like"></div>
<div id="layer8"></div>
<div id="layer7"></div>
<div id="watchthisvideo"></div>
<div id="id5video"></div>
<div id="videoliteral">
<iframe width="389" height="217" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ogSI0DscP_4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="shadow"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using Chrome there is a known issue where the facebook page itself (not the iFrame) actually has a horizontal scrollbar. They haven't fixed it yet. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182748101891780

Answer (score 0):

You have several things wrong by looking at the page. You should get the designer to fix it.  It seems designed for a width greater than Facebook allows, which is 520px.  To start, in maidpro.css, set the #maidPro width to 520 or less, and anything wider than that start shrinking.  And then removing "left" values to shift the items back over.

Comment: *sidenote:* as of 2013, Page Tab app can have larger width, 810px, which can be toggled between 510 & 810px in Page Tab Settings

Answer (score 0):

Set the css in this way to remove the scrollbar

```
body {
            width:520px;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            }
```

and use FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

Answer (score 0):

The answer here: [Facebook App - Javascript Set Height of Canvas?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7031977/facebook-app-javascript-set-height-of-canvas/7279020#7279020) is the best solution

I had this problem too and the usual approach didn't seem to work. But after using the tricks mentioned in that post, I managed to finally get rid of the scrollbars.